# How can I deserialize JSON and pull out a certain value?

Tags: c#, json

I have my JSON in a string. How can I use JavascriptSerializer to deserialize it and find the value of SSOID?

```
{
"Addresses":  [
    {
        "Address": "123 Test Road",
        "State": "Mississippi"
    }
],
"Birthdate": "April 12 2012",
"CreateDate": "April 13 2012",
"IDs": [
    {
        "isDefault": false,
        "PurchaseID": "883"
    }
],
"Sex": "Male",
"SSOID": 23444,
"Suffix": null,
"BoardID": 4324
}
```

Comment: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case:

```
string s = "your json string";   
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var obj = js.DeserializeObject(s) as Dictionary<string,object>;
int ssoid = (int)obj["SSOID"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserialized = (Dictionary<string, object>) js.DeserializeObject(json);
var ssoid = (int) deserialized["SSOID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var SSOID = new JavaScriptSerializer()
                    .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json)["SSOID"];
```

OR

```
dynamic jObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json);
var SSOID = jObj["SSOID"];
```